# Replace value stored in xml using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, xml, replace

I have a xml data column in the table
in which I want to replace values using stored procedure

my xml is like

```
<Rooms>
<Room Id=798 >
<Supplier Name ="xyz" Number="123">
</Room>
<Room Id=799 >
<Supplier Name ="xyz" Number="123">
</Room>
</Rooms>
```

I want to replace supplier number in both rooms

number of rooms will vary from 2-5 so I need a loop to run through

I tried

Update [Table name] Set Data.Modify('replace Value of (//Room/Supplier/@Number)[1] with @newValue ')

only 1st supplier number is modified and second remains the same

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. Please fix it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix your XML to make it well-formed.

Here it is how to implement it in MS SQL Server.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT @tbl (xml_data) VALUES
(N'<Rooms>
    <Room Id="798">
        <Supplier Name="xyz" Number="123"/>
    </Room>
    <Room Id="799">
        <Supplier Name="xyz" Number="123"/>
    </Room>
</Rooms>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @new_number VARCHAR(10) = 'fafa';

DECLARE @UPDATE_STATUS BIT = 1;
    
WHILE @UPDATE_STATUS > 0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET xml_data.modify('replace value of 
      (/Rooms/Room/Supplier[@Number != sql:variable("@new_number")]/@Number)[1] 
      with sql:variable("@new_number")')
    FROM @tbl AS t
    WHERE xml_data.exist('/Rooms/Room/Supplier[@Number != sql:variable("@new_number")]')=1;
        
    SET @UPDATE_STATUS = @@ROWCOUNT;
    PRINT @UPDATE_STATUS;
END;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
<Rooms>
  <Room Id="798">
    <Supplier Name="xyz" Number="fafa" />
  </Room>
  <Room Id="799">
    <Supplier Name="xyz" Number="fafa" />
  </Room>
</Rooms>
```

Comment: Good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. 
Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted".